# How to expose dgraph-ratel-public without LoadBalancer in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean, dgraph

Whenever I expose a Kubernetes Service as a Load Balancer the external-IP is in forever `pending` state.

So, I am not able to access the `dgraph ratle` through my browser.

I needed to expose my Service through NodePort so that I can access it with `IP:node-port`.

Here I created a NodePort Service for my `dgraph ratle` public. I can `curl` `IP:node-port` and able to get the result but I cannot access it in my web browser.
I'm using Kubernetes on Digital Ocean
Kubernetes version `v1.12`.

Help me with:

1. Get pending external-IP or
2. Exposing the container in public or
3. What am I missing?

[image: kubectl describe svc dgraph-ratle-public]

Comment: can you provide `kubectl describe service service_name`?

Comment: hey @aurelius i have just added that in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reach [private IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) over the Internet, so you need to create a Load Balancer in front of your Kubernetes cluster, or some kind of VPN into your cluster.

Kubernetes default [cloud controller manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/running-cloud-controller/) doesn't support DigitalOcean. You can create a Load Balancer for Kubernetes cluster nodes manually, or you need to install an additional [cloud-controller-manager for DigitalOcean cloud](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager)  as it is mentioned in the [manual](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md):

> 1. Clone the git repo:

```
    $ git clone https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager.git
```

> 2. To run digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager, you need a DigitalOcean personal access token. If you are already logged in, you can create one [here](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/settings/api/tokens). Ensure the token you create has both read and write access.
> 3. Once you have a personal access token, create a Kubernetes Secret as a way for the cloud controller manager to access your token. ([using script](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/scripts/generate-secret.sh), [or manually](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#manually))
> 4. Deploy [appropriate version](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#version) of cloud-controller-manager:

```
    $ kubectl apply -f releases/v0.1.10.yml
    deployment "digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager" created
```

> NOTE: the deployments in releases/ are meant to serve as an example. They will work in a majority of cases but may not work out of the box for your cluster.
>
> Cloud Controller Manager current version is: v0.1.10. This means that the project is still under active development and may not be production ready. The plugin will be bumped to v1.0.0 once the DigitalOcean Kubernetes product is released.

Here you can find examples:

- [Load balancers](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/tree/master/docs/controllers/services/examples)
- [Node Features with Digitalocean Cloud Controller Manager](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/tree/master/docs/controllers/node/examples)